# Variable transformation for a multiple linear regression model

Tags: statistics, least-squares, estimation, parameter-estimation, linear-regression

[image: Assignment]

I can only transform C) in a way that leaves me with only constants for the parameters. In all other functions I either end up with $ln(\beta_1)$ or need to take the square root of $\beta$, etc. I'm also assuming that they messed up the subscripts so that $x_{1i}$ is actually supposed to be $x_{2i}$, otherwise none of them would be usable, right?

Comment: What's wrong with estimating a function of $\beta_j$? Why not apply the inverse function post estimation?

Comment: Also, where do you think they messed up subscripts? It looks to me that for each observation $i$, they split their vector of regressors into two parts (arbitrarily labelled), namely $x_{1i}$ and $x_{2i}$.

Comment: @Golder_Ratio the problem is that the parameters space could be restricted and so using OLS is not possible, for example having $\sqrt{\beta}$ means $\alpha = \sqrt\beta \geq 0$

Comment: but then indeed when you have for example $\log{\beta}$ can be considered strictly OLS I think so maybe it is a) and c)

Comment: @Tortar I've been trying to figure that out for a while now. I can transform a) into a log-log functional form, but it leaves me with ln(β_1) and the error term ln(ε_i) and I can't find out if that would be considered as linear parameters.

Comment: @Miriam Va look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482099/in-regression-y-beta-0-beta-12x-1-beta-2-x-2-isnt-beta-12-just?rq), as you can see since there is a $\beta^2$ this means OLS can't be used. Instead with $\ln \beta_1$ you can consider it linear because there are no restrinctions, also you don't obtain $\ln(\epsilon_i)$ but just $\epsilon_i$

Comment: thank you @Tortar!